# What is the best free api for ETHEREUM price

Tags: external-api

I use the api below for bitcoin price :
https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json
But coindesk hasn't `ETHEREUM` price in it's api.
What api should i use to get `ETHEREUM` price?

---

Also the api below does not work any more :
https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try https://min-api.cryptocompare.com.

Here is an example of how you can fetch information programmatically:

```
const request = require("request");

request.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD,EUR,CNY,JPY,GBP", function(error, response, body) {
    if (error)
        throw error;
    else if (!response)
        throw new Error("no response");
    else if (response.statusCode != 200)
        throw new Error("bad response");
    else
        console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(body), null, 4));
});
```

Comment: Really thanks dear, Is it free or will close after a while?

Comment: @SilverLight: I'm not the owner of this web-service, you know. Please feel free to accept the answer (by clicking on the V next to it), if you feel that it has answered your question.

Comment: Thanks, But it seems it is not free & has limitations. I want to use it in my web site. daily 200 300 users will call this api.

Comment: @SilverLight: No problem. Was free last time I used it.

Comment: They say use an api key, It seems it has 100,000 calls for one month limit.

Comment: There should be an unlimited api out there - just for eth price.

Comment: What do you think about this one : https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd

Comment: It seems that request npm package is deprecated now
Here is the updated code : 
```const requests = require("requests");

requests("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD,EUR,CNY,JPY,GBP")
.on('data', data => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data), null, 4));
});
```